# Is it possible to have CoreBluetooth Always On and Scanning?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, core-bluetooth

I know you can always scan for iBeacons via CoreLocation, but is it possible to always scan for BLE (non-iPhone peripheral) advertising data through CoreBluetooth? By always, I mean if I don't open the app for days at a time or shut my phone off and back on.

From my research, it sounds like you can scan in the background via CoreBluetooth, but that it will shut off if the iPhone has too much going on or if the iPhone is turned off and on, but that this can be done with CoreLocation (or via the Apple MFi program).

Comment: You can scan in the background but you need to specify the Service UUID you are interested in. In order to support scanning for a long period (where your app may have been terminated from the background) you need to implement Bluetooth state restoration. It is covered in the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
[manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
```

This enables `didDiscoverPeripheral` callback about every 100ms. This includes the RSSI of each device it sees.

You are right that you can scan in background as well. From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:):

> Apps that have specified the bluetooth-central background mode are
>   allowed to scan while in the background. That said, they must
>   explicitly scan for one or more services by specifying them in the
>   serviceUUIDs parameter.